# What is the probability of something happening twice

Tags: probability

An event occurs independently with probability $11/17$, what is the probability that after $n$ attempts the event has occurred at least twice?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "exactly twice" or "atleast twice"?

Comment: I mean " at least twice" sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite.  The number of occurrences $X$ in $n$ attempts has the binomial distribution with parameters $11/17$ and $n$.  You want $1-P(X<2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of it happening $0$ times is $(6/17)^n$.

The probability of it happening $1$ times is $n C 1 (6/17)^{n-1} (11/17)$.

So the answer would be:

$1 - (6/17)^n - n(6/17)^{n-1}(11/17)$.

Plug in $n = 4$ to get some intuition.

It is $≈1 - 0.02 - 0.11 = 0.87$.

Comment: In your second line, you intended to write $$\binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{6}{17}\right)^{n - 1}\left(\frac{11}{17}\right)$$

Comment: thanks :p. silly typo